# Using posix pipe() and dup() with C++ to redirect I/O problems

Tags: c++, shell, posix, pipe

I have to modify a simple shell I wrote for a previous homework assignment to handle I/O redirection and I'm having trouble getting the pipes to work. It seems that when I write and read to stdout and from stdin after duplicating the file descriptors in the separates processes, the pipe works, but if I use anything like printf, fprintf, gets, fgets, etc to try and see if the output is showing up in the pipe, it goes to the console even though the file descriptor for stdin and stdout clearly is a copy of the pipe (I don't know if that's the correct way to phrase that, but the point is clear I think).

I am 99.9% sure that I am doing everything as it should be at least in plain C -- such as closing all the file descriptors appropriately after the dup() -- and file I/O works fine, so this seems like an issue of a detail that I am not aware of and cannot find any information on. I've spent most of the day trying different things and the past few hours googling trying to figure out if I could redirect cin and cout to the pipe to see if that would fix it, but it seems like it's more trouble than it's worth at this point.

Should this work just by redirecting stdin and stdout since cin and cout are supposed to be sync'd with stdio? I thought it should, especially since the commands are probably written in C so they would use stdio, I would think. However, if I try a command like "cat [file1] [file2] | sort", it prints the result of cat [file1] [file2] to the command line, and the sort doesn't get any input so it has no output. It's also clear that cout and cin are not affected by the dup() either, so I put two and two together and came to this conclusion
Here is a somewhat shortened version of my code minus all the error checking and things like that, which I am confident I am handling well. I can post the full code if it come to it, but it's a lot so I'll start with this.

I rewrote the function so that the parent forks off a child for each command and connects them with pipes as necessary and then waits for the child processes to die. Again, write and read on the file descriptors 0 and 1 work (i.e. write to and reads from the pipe), stdio on the FILE pointers stdin and stdout do not work (do not write to pipe).

Thanks a lot, this has been killing me...

UPDATE: I wasn't changing the string cmd for each of the different commands so it didn't appear to work because the pipe just went to the same command so the final output was the same... Sorry for the dumbness, but thanks because I found the problem with strace.

```
int call_execv( string cmd, vector<string> &argv, int argc,
    vector<int> &redirect)
{
    int result = 0, pid, /* some other declarations */;
    bool file_in, file_out, pipe_in, pipe_out;
    queue<int*> pipes; // never has more than 2 pipes

    // parse, fork, exec, & loop if there's a pipe until no more pipes
    do
    {
        /* some declarations for variables used in parsing */
        file_in = file_out = pipe_in = pipe_out = false;

        // parse the next command and set some flags
        while( /* there's more redirection */ )
        {
            string symbol = /* next redirection symbol */

            if( symbol == ">" )
            {
                /* set flags, get filename, etc */
            }   
            else if( symbol == "<" )
            {
                /* set flags, get filename, etc */
            }
            else if( pipe_out = (symbol == "|") )
            {
                    /* set flags, and... */
                int tempPipes[2];               
                pipes.push( pipe(tempPipes) );
                break;
            }
        }

        /* ... set some more flags ... */

        // fork child
        pid = fork();
        if( pid == 0 )  // child
        {
            /* if pipe_in and pipe_out set, there are two pipes in queue. 
            the old pipes read  is dup'd to stdin, and the new pipes
            write is dup'd to stdout, other two FD's are closed */

            /* if only pipe_in or pipe_out, there is one pipe in queue.
            the unused end is closed in whichever if statement evaluates */

            /* if neither pipe_in or pipe_out is set, no pipe in queue */

            // redirect stdout
            if( pipe_out ){
                // close newest pipes read end
                close( pipes.back()[P_READ] );

                // dup the newest pipes write end
                dup2( pipes.back()[P_WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO );

                // close newest pipes write end
                close( pipes.back()[P_WRITE] );
            }
            else if( file_out ) 
                freopen(outfile.c_str(), "w", stdout);

            // redirect stdin
            if( pipe_in ){
                close( pipes.front()[P_WRITE] );
                dup2( pipes.front()[P_READ], STDIN_FILENO );
                close( pipes.front()[P_READ] );
            }
            else if ( file_in ) 
                freopen(infile.c_str(), "r", stdin);


            // create argument list and exec
            char **arglist = make_arglist( argv, start, end );
            execv( cmd.c_str(), arglist );

            cout << "Execution failed." << endl;    
            exit(-1); // this only executes is execv fails

        }   // end child

        /* close the newest pipes write end because child is writing to it.
           the older pipes write end is closed already */
        if( pipe_out ) 
            close( pipes.back()[P_WRITE] );

        // remove pipes that have been read from front of queue
        if( init_count > 0 )    
        {
            close( pipes.front()[P_READ] ); // close FD first
            pipes.pop();                    // pop from queue
        }   

    } while ( pipe_out );

    // wait for each child process to die

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Oh, some other things. I tried using a file (using a tmpnam() to generate a unique filename) to have the child processes write to as a pipe, then close, and read from as pipe. I'm fairly certain that the logistics of it (as is having separate files for separate "pipes") were fine, but I'm wondering if there might be an issue with flushing and stuff that might explain why that didn't work out? Also, to be clear, file I/O works with freopen, piping to files did not work with freopen, and this is not working with pipe and dup.

Comment: Another detail to draw attention to: reading and writing from/to file descriptors 0 and 1 works, but stdio stream input and output goes to the console. Can that be explained by the dup not working or is that an issue with mixing iostream and stdio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever the problem, you are *not checking any return values*. How do you know if the `pipe()` or the `dup2()` command succeeded? Have you verified that `stdout` and `stdin` really point to the pipe right before `execv`? Does `execv` keep the filedescriptors you give it? Not sure, here is the corresponding paragraph from the `execve` documentation:

- By default, file descriptors remain open across an execve().  File descriptors that are marked close-on-exec are closed; see the description of FD_CLOEXEC in fcntl(2).  (If a
        file descriptor is closed, this will cause the release of all record locks obtained on the underlying file by this process.  See fcntl(2)  for  details.)   POSIX.1-2001  says
        that  if file descriptors 0, 1, and 2 would otherwise be closed after a successful execve(), and the process would gain privilege because the set-user_ID or set-group_ID per‐
        mission bit was set on the executed file, then the system may open an unspecified file for each of these file descriptors.  As  a  general  principle,  no  portable  program,
        whether privileged or not, can assume that these three file descriptors will remain closed across an execve().

You should add more debug output and see what really happens. Did you use `strace -f` (to follow children) on your program?

Comment: I said in my original post, "Here is a somewhat shortened version of my code minus all the error checking and things like that, which I am confident I am handling well." I check the return value on the pipe, the fork (even for -1), all the dups and the freopens. I'm trying the strace and noticing some potential problems so thanks for that recommendation, I didn't know about it before. Also, I'm fairly sure execv is keeping the file descriptors because the file I/O works and I tried setting the FD_CLOEXEC flags to see what it did and it complained when they closed, which it doesn't do normally.

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
queue<int*> pipes; // never has more than 2 pipes
// ...
int tempPipes[2];               
pipes.push( pipe(tempPipes) );
```

Is not supposed to work. Not sure how it compiles since the result of [`pipe()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pipe.2.html) is `int`. Note only that, `tempPipes` goes out of scope and its contents get lost.

Should be something like that:

```
struct PipeFds
{
    int fds[2];
};

std::queue<PipeFds> pipes;
PipeFds p;
pipe(p.fds); // check the return value
pipes.push(p);
```

Comment: I think I put the pipe() in the push() when I was boiling down the code because that definitely wouldn't work, but my code works now. I also realized at some point that the int array would go out of scope, but forgot to fix it. It still worked though, I'm guessing because nothing else is allocated on the stack between the push() and dup()'s. Thanks for pointing this out, would have forgotten all about it otherwise.